# What is the meaning of $ \mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

In linear algebra, what does it mean to go from $\mathbb{R}^1$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: It's useful when asking questions about terminology to give an entire sentence. The context is important. Help people help you.

Answer (score 2):

It means to bring a two dimensional space to a three dimensional space, i.e., mapping vectors of the form $(x,y)$ to vectors of the form $(x,y,z).$ This must be done by applying some kind of linear transformation.

Comment: would you please show me an example using matrices?

Comment: You can think of the pair $(x,y)$ as a $2x1$ matrix and the pair $(x,y,z)$ as a $3x1$ matrix. One example could be $T(x,y) = (x,y,0).$ So $T(1,1) = (1,1,0).$ This takes a point in 2 dimensional space and brings it to the point in 3 dimensional space that leaves the z-axis constant at $0.$

Comment: how can you tell what dimension a matrix is  in? Is a 2x1 vector a one dimensional vector or two dimensional vector? Is a 3x1 vector a one dimensional vector of a two dimensional vector?

Comment: The dimension of a matrix is the amount of rows when there is only one column. So a $2x1$ matrix sits in two dimensional space

Comment: What is the purpose of having multiple columns in matrices? Do more than one columns in a matrix denote multiple planes?

Comment: What does multiplying a matrix of one column that sits in a 3 dimensional space by a scalar do geometrically?

Comment: If we are thinking of matrices as linear transformation multiple columns allow the transformation to use addition in the operation they perform. This is because linear transformations can be represented in a matrix and performed by matrix multiplication

Comment: Geometrically multiplying a matrix with one column by a scalar will stretch or shrink the vector by the scalar it is multiplied by

Comment: How can you stretch or shrink a vector? I believe that a vector can be 3-D.  Anything 3-D is a plane extending infinitely in all directions. I believe planes cannot be stretched or shrinked. Let's say a matrix with three rows and one column called A is multiplied by a scalar and the result is B. Do planes A and B have infinitely many solutions/points of intersection in common?

Comment: Geometrically stretching or shrinking is just extending the line that is graphed. Try graphing the vector $(1,1)$ versus the vector $(3,3).$ the vector $(3,3)$ is essentially on top of $(1,1)$ but is stretched to be longer.

Comment: is a vector a line or a point?

Comment: You should find a human to talk to, @Zapoitsqun . You have a *lot* of questions...

Comment: A vector in 2 dimensional space is a line. The vector $(1,1)$ extends from the point $(0,0)$ to the point $(1,1).)

Comment: A vector always extends from the origin (0,0,0)?

Comment: If we are talking about vectors in real space, yes

Comment: Why must the transformation be linear?  I'm not sure I get that.

Comment: If we are talking about linear algebra we must be talking about linear transformations

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example. Let's take a vector from $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$. The left hand side has the (transformation)(2D vector) = (3D vector) on the right side.
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\c & d\\e & f\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} ax+ by\\cx + dy\\ex + fy\end{pmatrix}$$

---

What's a real space $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $n$? Let's explore this by visualizing some familiar spaces:

- A line is a 1D space, $\mathbb{R}$. You need only one coordinate $x$ to identify where you are. In this case, you don't need a vector... Since we only need one number, we have a scalar.
- A plane is 2D space, $\mathbb{R}^2$. You need two coordinates $(x,y)$ to locate a point. Instead of using an ordered pair, we can use a vector $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$.
- The world we live in is $\mathbb{R}^3$ from Euclid's point of view. As a vector a location can be specified by $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$. Note that the number of entries in the column denotes the dimension.
- Higher dimensional spaces extend this idea. For an $n$-dimensional space, you can represent a point's location y a $n \times 1$ vector $\begin{pmatrix}x^{(1)}\\x^{(2)}\\x^{(3)}\\\vdots\\x^{(n)}\end{pmatrix}$.

The example above multiples a 2D *vector* on the left by some $3\times 2$ transformation *matrix*. The result is a 3D *vector*.

Comment: is a,b,c,d,e,f a 1-d vector of a 2-d vector? How can you tell? Is x,y 1d or 2d?

Comment: @Zapoitsqun See edit.

Comment: Shouldn't the matrix (let's call it Y) with a,b,c,d,e,f be matrix that sits in a 3d space as Y has 3 rows? If Y has three rows, then shouldn't Y be a 3-D vector? Are you sure this is ℝ2→ℝ3 instead of ℝ3→ℝ3? In short, does number of rows = dimension number?

Comment: No and no, $\mathbf{Y}$ is a matrix of dimension $3\times 2$. A matrix, in a sense, is made up of many column (or row) vectors. Yes.

Comment: The dimension of a vector will be $n$ for a $n\times 1$ column or $1\times n$ row.

Answer (score 0):

Let $T$ be a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be denoted by the matrix: $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \\ 5 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$.

Then, $T$ sends vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ to $ \mathbb{R}^{3}$, for example: $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \\ 5 & 6 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}7 \\ 15 \\ 23 \end{bmatrix}$$

i.e.
$$ \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 3\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{2} $$
but 
$$ \begin{bmatrix}7 \\ 15 \\ 23 \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{3} $$